# Is there a method or property (related to PivotCache / PivotCaches) to identify why a pivotcache cannot be created?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm using XLS VBA code to create pivot tables based on named ranges.
As I'm getting an error code while invoking the CreatePivotTable, I noticed that the PivotCache never has been created. I cannot figure out the reason. Is there a way to deep-dive into PivotCaches.Create errors?

I already tried to define SourceData

- with named range
- with absolute references
- with relative references
- one step-by-step replacing each item with its string value

various declarations (`wBk as Workboook`, `wSh as WorkSheet`, `kchPivot as PivotCache`, `piPivot as PivotTable`, `DataSourceRge as Range`, `DataSourceString as String` ...)

```
Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wSh = wBk.Sheets("MP_1_30")
Set DataSourceRge = Range("MP_1_30_Type_Ctl")
```

A) this does not work

```
Set kchPivot = wBk.PivotCaches.Create (xlDataBase, DataSourceRge)
```

B) this doesn't work either

```
DataSourceString  = wSh.Name & "!" & _ 
DataSourceRge.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Set kchPivot = wBk.PivotCache.Create (xlDataBase, DataSourceString)
```

IMPORTANT: DataSourceRge is a ONE column range (nb: all the ranges for which I want to automate the creation of pivot tables are 1 column-wide)

I place the following control to ascertain the creation of the PivotCache

```
MsgBox wBk.PivotCaches.Count
```

I always receive "0" (nil) but would expect "1"

Comment: Generally, it's encouraged to fully qualify ranges, as the default-assumed sheet is the `ActiveSheet`. Right now, `Set DataSourceRge = Range("MP_1_30_Type_Ctl")` implicitly means `Set DataSourceRge = ActiveSheet.Range("MP_1_30_Type_Ctl")`. I think you would probably want to do `Set DataSourceRge = wSh.Range("MP_1_30_Type_Ctl")`

Comment: Many thanks! Very valuable comment to avoid possible mismatches. I cleansed the entire code. Unfortunately, does not solve the issue although code is much more consistent!

Comment: ...and this doesn't work either

Comment: ...and this doesn't work either Set kchPivot = wBk.PivotCaches,Create(xlDataBase, wSh.Range(wSh.Cells ( fRow, fCol), wSh.Cells (lRow, lCol)))

Comment: Regarding the previous comment -- there's a comma between PivotCaches and Create -- it should be a period.

Comment: Indeed, it's a period

Comment: Sorry, not sure if we're understanding each other. You said that line of code didn't work for you. In the comment, the code has a comma where it should be a period. I tested that line with some mocked up data in a workbook; and after changing the comma for a period, it appeared to run fine for me. So, from my perspective, the only issue with the code was the comma. If it's having issues, it may be from one of the other variables.

Comment: are there any features (e.g. in XL options, ...) that would prevent a PivotCache to be created?

Comment: Sorry. In my code, it's also a period; but is doesn't work; lRow, LCol, fRow, FCol are defined as Long; all individual variables seems fine but wBk.PivotCaches.Count still is NIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not getting any reported error messages, I believe the issue is that you aren't creating any "display items" *(pivottable, pivotchart, etc.)* which are using that pivotcache. I did some testing with the code. You should be able to replicate my results with the attached code, and the data setup shown in the image below.

Using a fresh workbook add sample data in column A of Sheet1, then add a second sheet (Note: my code uses code names for the sheets, so if you're not starting from a brand new workbook, you may need change the codenames in the assignments of the sheet variables

In the code, I have two locations where I use a MsgBox to get the count of pivotcaches. Both are after the "creation" of the pivotcach. One is before creating a pivottable with that cache, the other is after.

When I run the code, the first MsgBox shows "0"; while the second MsgBox shows "1".

Although, I can't find documentation on this phenomenon; my assumption is as follows:

---

*To help keep Excel files from becoming bloated, there is an automated process which either clears out unused pivotcaches - that is, pivotcaches without any associated items (pivottable, pivotchart, etc.)  - and/or prevents the pivotcache from being finalized before a display item is associated with it.*

*Therefore, to fully create, and finalize, a pivotcache, at least one of the desired displays items must also be created using that pivotcache.*

---

If for some reason, you really can't create any of the desired display items at the time of the pivotcache creation, my suggestion would be to create a "dummy" display item on a veryhidden sheet which can be deleted after adding some actual display items to that pivotcache. ***(FYI: Also in my testing, I tried created a dummy display item, then immediately deleted it. This resulted in the automatic deletion of the pivotcache as well.)***

[image: sample data]

```
Sub test()
    Set wBk = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsh = Sheet1
    Set sht2 = Sheet2
    fRow = 1
    fCol = 1
    lRow = 5
    lCol = 1

    Set kchPivot = wBk.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wsh.Range(wsh.Cells(fRow, fCol), wsh.Cells(lRow, lCol)))

    MsgBox wBk.PivotCaches.Count 'Does not increment for newly created pivotcache with no associated display items

    With kchPivot
        .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=sht2.Range("D3"), TableName:="Performance"
    End With

    MsgBox wBk.PivotCaches.Count 'Increments for pivotcache now associated with a pivottable
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant! I can only concur.. while mimicking the code via macro-recorder, I notice PivotCache.Count started to increment; then deleting the pivot-tables created by macro, the count still stayed frozen to NIL…. Must indeed exists some kind of undocumented feature forcing users to keep links between caches and related pivots…. Could be very puzzling if creations of PivotTables is nested in subroutines…. Many thanks for your valuable time

Comment: @jm_lux8832 You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.  :)